# integrate PHP code with contact form 7 fields

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to get the values of the contact-form-7 field and store them into the PHP variable. I am going to make a booking form in which I have 2 selection categories based on that I want to decrement the value of the variable.

I open the contact-form-7 code and directory but not get where the files are store.
my WordPress booking from look like

https://prnt.sc/o3g1a9

Here is the PHP code example

```
<?php
$cow = 100;
$goat = 200;
if (isset($_POST['cow']) || isset($_POST['goat'])) {
if(isset($_POST['cow'])){
    $cowSelect = $_POST['cow'];
    switch ($cowSelect) {
        case '1':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '2':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '3':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '4':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '5':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '6':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '7':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '8':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        case '9':
          $cow = ($cow - $_POST['cow']);
          echo 'Total ' .$cow. ' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
          break;
        default:
          echo 'please select the category';
          break;
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['goat'])){
    $goatSelect = $_POST['goat'];
    switch ($goatSelect) {
        case '1':
          $goat = ($goat - $_POST['goat']);
          echo 'Total '.$goat. ' goats remaning'.'<br/>';
        break;
        case '2':
          $goat = ($goat - $_POST['goat']);
          echo 'Total '.$goat. ' goats remaning'.'<br/>';
        break;
        case '3':
          $goat = ($goat - $_POST['goat']);
          echo 'Total '.$goat. ' goats remaning'.'<br/>';
        break;
        case '4':
          $goat = ($goat - $_POST['goat']);
          echo 'Total '.$goat. ' goats remaning'.'<br/>';
        break;
        case '5':
          $goat = ($goat - $_POST['goat']);
          echo 'Total '.$goat. ' goats remaning'.'<br/>';
        break;

        default:
            echo 'please select the category';
        break;
    }
}
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="cow">
          <option value="">Select cow</option>

        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>

    </select>
    <select name="goat">
      <option value="">Select goat</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

I made the PHP code example but I want the same work for WordPress contact-form-7
help me how to do integrate the PHP code with contact-form-7 ? or how to get the contact-form-7 values to do the same work as PHP code do?

Comment: search for contact form 7 hooks.

Comment: can you please clear the answer If I find the hooks then how I will set it? Can you please make a short example through which I can getting the idea of how I will do this work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into the Hooks the Contact Form 7 provides. You'll hook into the response to output what you want.

As for the dropdowns, you create them in the Contact Form 7 form editor with the provided options.

You can see a list of hooks at http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/5.1.3/hooks/#index=a (for the latest version of CF7), you'll probably want something like the `wpcf7_ajax_json_echo` hook to modify the outbound response returned to the user.  Here's an example:

Something like this (untested), but it would go in your wp-content/themes/footheme/functions.php (your theme, functions file).

```php
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_json_echo', function( $response, $result )
{
    $cow  = 100;
    $goat = 200;

    if (isset($response['cow']) || isset($response['goat'])) {
        if (isset($response['cow'])) {
            $cowSelect = $response['cow'];
            $cow = ($cow - $response['cow']);

            switch ($cowSelect) {
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                    $message .= 'Total '.$cow.' cows remaning'.'<br/>';
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (isset($response['goat'])) {
            $goatSelect = $response['goat'];
            $goat = ($goat - $response['goat']);

            switch ($goatSelect) {
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                    $message .= 'Total '.$goat.' goats remaning'.'<br/>';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $response;
}, 10, 2);
```

Then you just need to create a dropdown with the options you want, make the dropdown required (if it needs to be required) in the Contact Form 7 form editor.

**Edit** an example of how to create dropdowns in CF7 editor:

```
[select cows "1" "2" "3"]
```

Comment: Hi! dear, thank you so much for a great answer. Can you please help me how to add dropdown and display in my form because I am very stuck with this problem.

thank you so much

Comment: You can see how to do it in the CF7 docs https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/ I've updated my answer to include an example of a dropdown in the CF7 editor.